# Как сделать прямоугольник, нарисованный с помощью SVG, прозрачным?

Tags: xml, svg

Всем привет, наконец-то конец рабочей недели! И снова вопрос про SVG (*Scalable Vector Graphics*) - Я рисую прямоугольник (ширина 93мм, высота 53мм) с помощью SVG, используя вот такую XML разметку:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<svg version="1.1" 
baseProfile="full" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" 
width="93mm" height="53mm">

<rect x="0" y="0" width="93mm" height="53mm" stroke="black" stroke-width="2px" fill="white" />

</svg>
```

Потом все остальное уже рисую внутри этого прямоугольника. Внимание вопрос - что мне нужно написать в свойстве fill="", вместо white, чтобы залить прямоугольник не **белым цветом**, а сделать его **прозрачным**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы задать прозрачность заливки фигуры, в SVG используется дополнительный атрибут [fill-opacity](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillOpacityProperty). Кроме того, есть смежные атрибуты: stroke-opacity - для определения прозрачности линий, и opacity - для определения общей прозрачности.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас приму Ваш ответ как лучший. Сейчас попробую воспользоваться предложенным Вами методом!

Answer (score -1):

Я погуглил хорошенько и нашел такую вещь: если указать свойство `fill="none"`, то фигура должна быть прозрачной, хотя я не уверен на 100%.

```
<rect x="0" y="0" width="93mm" height="53mm" stroke="black" stroke-width="2px" fill="none" />
```